# How can I get Rtools working on Windows with R 2.15.2?

Tags: r

After installing Rtools 3.0 for Windows, I ran the following command at the R console:

```
> library(devtools)
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 2.15.2 was found.
(Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.0)

Please download and install Rtools 2.16 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
> find_rtools()
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 2.15.2 was found.
(Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.0)

Please download and install Rtools 2.16 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
```

However, the web page http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ does not list a version 2.16. Also, it says that version 3.0 is compatible with all version of R > 2.15.1. Does anybody know how to make Rtools work with R 2.15.2 on Windows?

Comment: I wonder if this a bug in `devtools` version checking, rather than an actual problem with Rtools? Although you get this warning, can you still compile things correctly with `R CMD INSTALL` and so on?

Comment: Given that these are Hadley's babies, I'm guessing you could get a faster answer on the manipulatr mailing list or maybe at an RStudio list, since devtools is distributed through them?

Comment: We've just pushed an update to CRAN.

Comment: how about 2.15.2 on Ubuntu Precise 64-bit? - package ‘devtools’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2) - or I could try building from source...

Answer (score 2):

This looks to have been fixed in early February 2013 by the push of the new version to CRAN as stated by @Hadley in the OP comments.

It works for me...